# Can NHibernate be configured to automatically call .CustomType<T> for all columns of a certain type?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a model that has a property of an Enum type:

```
public virtual Units Unit { get; set; } // Units is an enum
```

I have a class called EnumMapper which handles some custom mapping logic I have for use with my database.  In my mapping, I have:

```
Map(x => x.Unit).CustomType<EnumMapper<Units>>();
```

This works great.  No problems at all.  However, I have quite a few models that have properties of type `Units` as well.  Rather than call `.CustomType<T>()` on each one of these, I'm wondering if I can add something to my `FluentConfiguration` object to tell NHibernate to use this type mapping on *any and all* properties of type `Units`.  Here's how I configure NHibernate so far:

```
private ISessionFactory InitializeSessionFactory()
{
   sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
      .Database(DatabaseConfiguration)
      .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
          .AddFromAssemblyOf<DatabaseAdapter>()
          .Conventions.Add(Table.Is(x => x.EntityType.Name.ToLowerInvariant())) // All table names are lower case
          .Conventions.Add(ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id"))                           // Foreign key references end with Id
          .Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Always()))
      .BuildSessionFactory();

   return sessionFactory;
}
```

I have a feeling that it's as simple as calling `.Conventions.Add()` on something else, but I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out one solution using `ConventionBuilder`:

```
.Conventions.Add(ConventionBuilder.Property.When(
  c => c.Expect(x => x.Type == typeof(GenericEnumMapper<Units>)),
  x => x.CustomType<EnumMapper<Units>>()
))
```

It's not super pretty, but it works.  I think a better solution might be to write my own [convention](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Conventions) that automatically maps an enum to its correct custom type.  I will post that here if I get it working.

**Update:** Cleaned this up a bit.  I've added a static method to my `EnumMapper<T>` class:

```
public class EnumMapper<T> : NHibernate.Type.EnumStringType<T>
{
   // Regular mapping code here

   public static IPropertyConvention Convention
   {
      get
      {
         return ConventionBuilder.Property.When(
            c => c.Expect(x => x.Type == typeof (GenericEnumMapper<T>)),
            x => x.CustomType<EnumMapper<T>>()
            );
      }
   }
}
```

Now I can just configure it with:

```
.Conventions.Add(EnumMapper<Units>.Convention)
```